# Call a function internally that expects a request and a response

Tags: node.js

I wrote a function to add a user:

```
exports.add = function(req, res) {
  UserRoles.create(req.body, function (err, musician) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
}
```

I understand that it is supposed to be called from client end/UI as it expects a request and a response.

However, Now, there is a need to be able to call it internally. That is, when a user registers itself,  ultimately that user needs to be added to database only, so I thought I should call this function in my registration code to avoid rewriting code.

It looks like this:

```
register: function(req, res, next) {
        try {
            User.validate(req.body);
        }
        catch(err) {
            return res.send(400, err.message);
        }

        User.add(/*what do I pass in here */ function(err, user) { --POINT OF PROBLEM
            if(err === 'UserAlreadyExists') return res.send(403, "User already exists");
            else if(err)                    return res.send(500);

            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if(err)     { next(err); }
                else        { res.json(200, { "role": user.role, "username": user.username }); }
            });
        });
    }
```

How do I avoid rewriting the code here for add? Is there a way I can call it from within `register`? If not, Can I get some pointers on doing this? I am a complete newbie and have very little knowledge in this so I would request an explanation with the suggested approach so that I understand what pros and cons one approach has over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest decoupling `User.add()` from `req/res` by just passing in the data object:

```
exports.add = function(user, callback) {
  UserRoles.create(user, callback);
  // This is short for:
  // UserRoles.create(user, function(err, musician) {
  //   if (err) return callback(err);
  //   return callback(null, musician);
  // });
};
```

You would call it like so:

```
User.add(req.body, function(err, user) {
  ...
});
```